# Faster way to load matrix into byte array?

Tags: arrays, performance, matrix, byte

I am overlaying a custom drawn view on top of a video frame and sending that overlay pixel information to my microcontroller and encoding it into a byte array. Most of the RGB values are 0 because they are apart of the video frame and not the custom view I am drawing.

I am encoding the 32-bit rgb value into 4 different bytes, for each pixel. However, the frame is very slow and lags because I am looping through the entire frame and converting each value to a byte array. I understand what's causing the issue, but wondering if there is a way to speed it up.

I would remove the 0's and only pass values that have a valid RGB value, but I need to keep the position.

The matrix size has 518400 elements.

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        byte *t = (byte *) &A.mem[i];
        byte t1 = t[0];
        byte t2 = t[1];
        byte t3 = t[2];
        byte t4 = t[3];
        if (t1 != '\0' || t2 != '\0' || t3 != '\0' || t4 != '\0') {
            writeSerialData(t, 4);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the four bytes against zero in one go:

```
int iMax = A.size();
for (int i = 0; i < iMax; ) {
        int32_t *t = (int32_t *) &A.mem[i++];

        if (*t) {
            writeSerialData(t, 4);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I have the write statement outside of the if statement and write even 1 byte, the time to complete the loop goes from 1-2ms to 400-500ms. Any ideas? There are no print statements inside `writeSerialData`

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the receiving part of that `writeSerialData()`? Then you should invent some encoding that specifies a new offset of the following data.

Also, are you using 16 millions colors in your overlay? If you are only using a few colors, they invented [palette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palette_(computing)) for that. If you know the colors upfront, you can hard-code them on both ends. If not - send a small header with that palette info before the image. That can cut the size of your data by 4 times. If you only have single color, you can further reduce your data to single bits.

**UPDATE**

By "encoding" I mean some special format of your data, other than simple RGB value. For example, do you use the Alpha channel (I noticed you didn't call your colors RGBA)? If not - you can use that byte for length-encoding, stating that the following color is repeated that many times (up to 255). This will save you some bandwidth on your zeroes (just say how many are there), as well as on a line of the same color (you don't need to send every pixel).

Comment: I do control the receiving part of `writeSerialData`. When you refer to that are you referring to reading 4 bytes at a time? Not sure I follow when you mention encoding. Right not I'm aiming for the flexibility of any color variation, but I will take a look into CLUT.

Comment: @joethemow - please see my update for encoding

Comment: @joethemow - is the issue resolved? would you please share - how?